# Why is my class not a BitmapFont if I am extending it

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have this class:

```
public class Font extends BitmapFont
{
    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
    FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;
    public Font()
    {
        generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator();
        parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = 30;
        parameter.color = Color.WHITE;
        this = generator.generateFont(parameter);
        generator.dispose();
    }
}
```

But on this line:

```
this = generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

I get an error, it says: *`required Font, found BitmapFont.`*

Now I dont get it why the compiler doesnt see my Font class as a BitmapFont. Do you guys know the reason and also know how I still can make the font assign to the class itself?

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile: you can't assign any value to `this`

Comment: you forget the basic rule of the major pillar of oops the 'polymorphism'.
@gimby really summarized it very nicely and I hope now you can figure out your mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the mistake that Raeffaele describes in the comments, you are not understanding a fundamental thing of OO here.

Take this simple *is-a* example: a Cow is an Animal. But an Animal is not always a Cow. It can also be a Sheep, or a Dog. And as we all know, a Dog and a Cow are completely different, even though they both inherit from Animal.

Now we apply that to your situation. A Font is-a BitmapFont, but a BitmapFont is not always a Font.

Given that, The

```
generator.generateFont(parameter);
```

call returns a LibGDX BitmapFont instance, not an instance of your own Font class. So it would be a very bad idea to try and assign it to a variable that demands an instance of Font anyway.

---

Shorter version.

You should understand that this works because Font is-a BitmapFont:

```
BitmapFont font = new Font();
```

and this does not because BitmapFont is not a Font:

```
Font font = new BitmapFont();
```

Your code is attempting to create the second situation, just in a slightly different way.

Comment: @Gimby allright now i get my mistake, but how am I supposed to that when I'm referencing to the class Font, I'm referencing to the actual font. Cause what I am doing right now is having a field member BitmapFont and put my font there, but if I want to access it, i have to go with         Font.font.<method/field>.

Comment: @Nahro The solution you have now is called "composition" and that is a good way to do it. You could add methods to your Font class which simply do that font.<method> call for you if you want to hide the inner BitmapFont from the outside world.